# Is removing a deleted user's name from their posts compatible with CC-BY-SA 4.0?

Tags: discussion, licensing

According to the Terms of Service, the content posted by a user is CC-BY-SA 4.0 licensed. But CC-BY requires attribution. A deleted user's content is missing attribution since their username is replaced on all content.

I see that there's some ambiguous wording in the terms of service.

> This means that you cannot revoke permission for Stack Overflow to publish, distribute, store and use such content and to allow others to have derivative rights to publish, distribute, store and use such content. The CC BY-SA 4.0 license terms are explained in further detail by Creative Commons, and the license terms applicable to content are explained in further detail [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/347758/creative-commons-licensing-ui-and-data-updates). You should be aware that all Public Content you contribute is available for public copy and redistribution, and all such Public Content must have appropriate attribution.

It seems to me, removing the username is effectively removing attribution and not honoring the license.

Similarly, a post that started by one person, but then gets converted to a community answer also seems against the license. The user's attribution is removed and replaced with "community".

Or maybe I'm misunderstanding and it's actually Stack Overflow that's supposed to get attribution, not the author of the question or answer?

Comment: Cross-site duplicate? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277440/when-se-unilaterally-alters-an-authors-name-to-user123xxx-isnt-it-breaching though I admit the license has changed since then.

Comment: Yes and no. There are other reasons attribution gets removed like when something gets converted to a community answer.

Comment: For CW you have the same kind of warning: "Are you sure you want to make this post Community Wiki?
**Doing so will remove explicit ownership**..."

Comment: In the post history you should have all attributions. Relevant for community wikis, not sure about deleted users...

Comment: *It seems to me, removing the username is effectively removing attribution and not honoring the license.* I would object the user name is not *removed*, but *reverted* to its original unique identifier, and therefore attribution remains. IANAL, though.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I would object to the objection. Attribution probably (IANAL) means to use the identifier that the content creator chose at the time of content creation. It doesn't need to be unique and later reversion of the attribution for whatever reason is not really part of the CC license unless it's the content creator who does it.

Comment: This question isn't really specific for StackOverflow. Is it fully answered by [animuson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/277443/260073) or is something left?

Comment: [The duplicate @Kaiido refers to](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277440/when-se-unilaterally-alters-an-authors-name-to-user123xxx-isnt-it-breaching) seems still relevant, in spite of license changes. In particular, the user is explicitly told that all content they had contributed will become anonymous. The user accepting these terms seems tantamount to them granting unattributed use of the content (since the use itself isn't revoked), if not outright transfer of copyright ownership (that seems more tenuous to me, but not being a lawyer, I can't rule it out).

Comment: @Trilarion, good point. Attribution in CC BY-SA [only speaks about "author" or "creator"](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/License_Versions#Attribution-specific_elements), and the [legal code](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/legalcode) (1.g) speaks of "individuals" or "entities". I would surmise that a unique user identifier legally defines an "individual" or an "entity", but it may very well be more complicated than that, and my head hurts already.

Comment: @Trilarion does the answer you linked to answer to the question? I don't see the answer commenting "does this behaviour breach the license" in any way

Comment: @eis I think the answer by animuson kind of states that it's all the will of the user, so it's fine with the license. Maybe it doesn't?

Comment: Username (rather than userid) is not unique. So username itself cannot identify somebody.

Comment: @Akina That may be a shortcoming of the CC license. However, attribution is typically a name and a link. Both together can be unique.

Comment: @Trilarion When user is deleted the link to his profile become invalid, is it? if so "a name and a link" cannot identify again.

Comment: @Akina Even invalid links can identify somebody. They just have to be unique for that. Lots of links on the internet are dead, but they still convey a structure. I think you concentrate too much on identification (in that case I would recommend retina scans, fingerprints, ...). The idea of the CC license attribution section is not to make identification 100% foolproof but to implement same practical way of claiming authorship, I think.

Comment: @Trilarion I have to disagree - to my eyes the answer just details the steps that stack exchange does in these cases, without mentioning the license in any way or form. If the answer doesn't even mention the license, that can't be an answer to the question "does this action breach the license or not"

Comment: Considerable amount of the content here is under older versions of Creative Commons. Is this question also interested in the status of deleted users content under CC-BY-SA versions < 4 or only 4.0?

Comment: @Kaiido, I could be wrong but AFAIK there are other ways for a Q or A to become "community" without permission of the original author. I certainly see Qs and As that appear to have been changed to "community" by mods. Also don't know if I agree that being able to see the history of edits would be enough for attribution. In almost any other context it would be considered against the license to effectively hide the attribution for any reason.

Comment: @samanthaj Since this is a collaborative site, the user card at the bottom of the post isn't enough to provide attribution on its own, CW or not. If, for instance, I post an answer and you edit it to add a new section, your contribution should also be attributed, and that is done through the revision history. Ultimately it's similar to Wikipedia, where attribution for the *prima facie* anonymous articles can be found in their history pages. See also 3(a)(2) in [the license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/legalcode) on satisfying the conditions "in any reasonable manner".

Comment: @duplode Reasonable is probably meant for cases where you can't simply print the attribution next to the work because you derived it in a different media for example. I'm not sure that hiding information behind a link is still reasonable. The edit history is basically a different location and it wouldn't hurt to print the names of all contributors below an answer.

Comment: @duplode I just wondered how I would properly attribute a Wikipedia page. Would I need to cite all the author's names and link to the page's history? I don't think I have seen people printing names of Wikipedia authors when citing from it.

Comment: [1/2] @Trilarion (1) I'm a layman, so take my opinion with a grain of salt, but anyway: I'm fairly confident it is reasonable. If Wikipedia can put attribution behind a link to discourage editors from claiming ownership, SO can put it behind a link to avoid having lots of names in small print at the bottom of each post.

Comment: [2/2] @Trilarion (2) [The Wikipedia guidance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Citing_Wikipedia) is indeed not to name individual contributors in citations, much like it wouldn't be done when citing a traditional encyclopedia. A permalink to the article revision being cited suffices. Things are different when it comes to reproducing content in offline media. For instance, e-books of Wikipedia or Wikibooks content will, if properly made, have a page somewhere with the full list of contributors.

Comment: @duplode Yes it seems as if putting attribution one link away could still be okay. It would depend a bit on how "reasonable" is defined in a legal context. I'm not a lawyer either but while it surely is convenient to not having to name all the authors directly below a work I wonder if that is really in the spirit of the CC licenses. Maybe law.stackexchange would be the best possible place to ask this question without directly consulting a lawyer.

Comment: I tried to google the meaning of "reasonable" in legal contexts because it plays such a prominent role in the CC license attribution rules and I'm even more confused than before. It seems that reasonable either means that you should use your brain (which would probably result in a thousand different outcomes according to whose brain is used) or that you should do what most other people would do (which means that the meaning of reasonable would possible change over time and might be difficult to estimate). At this point I give up trying to find an answer to this question.

Answer (score 28):

### Deletion

> User deletion is irreversible! By sending this request, your votes will be revoked, and all of your content will be made anonymous.

Like the [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleting-account) says (and the [privacy policy](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/privacy-policy) and also the [message shown to the user deleting their account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7979/323179)), when a user tries to delete their account, they are also requesting that their username be removed from all their content (aka a [request to remove attribution](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/License%20Versions#Licensors_may_request_removal_of_attribution)), so a different aspect of the license is relevant:

> CC licenses require licensees to remove attribution to the creator at his or her request, where it would otherwise be required to include it.

All other deletions (now) are due to Terms of Service violations, which may or may not allow Stack Exchange to legally remove the username chosen by the user. In some cases, when the user was underage, they can’t legally keep the username, given that it’s probably personal information.

### Community Wiki

While the post may not be attributed to the original poster when viewing the entire Q&A thread, the attribution still exists in the edit history ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/927386/revisions)), where it’s feasible to  give attribution to every author. Therefore I don’t see a problem.

Comment: The rule is that the votes of heavy voters may be reassigned to Community, if the user didn’t ever engage in vote fraud. I posted a [request to change the wording in the Help Center here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/361042/323179). (What happens to a deleted user’s votes has nothing to do with the rest of my answer.)

Comment: @SagarV your assertion is wrong; you appear to be confusing post deletion with account deletion. Barring very specific exceptions (which are handled manually by the CM team), **all** votes will be reverted when an account is deleted.  Age of the votes has *nothing* to do with this here. Only when a specific *post* is deleted does the 60 day rule apply, not to the age of the votes but to the age of the post, and then only if the post has a score of 3 or more.

Comment: @MartijnPieters ok my memory problem. But why the community have over 1.7M votes?

Comment: @SagarV: See [Why does the Community user have votes cast?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230610), the majority are automatic downvotes.

Answer (score 6):

Laurel pointed out the related legal basis in a link, but the full context is a bit more complex. To quote the direct CC FAQ on this topic we find:

> #### What can I do if I offer my material under a Creative Commons license and I do not like the way someone uses it?
>
> [...] **Second, licensors may waive the attribution requirement, choosing not to be identified as the licensor, if they wish.** Third, if the licensor does not like how the material has been modified or used, CC licenses require that the licensee remove the attribution information upon request. (In 3.0 and earlier, this is only a requirement for adaptations and collections; in 4.0, this also applies to the unmodified work.) Finally, anyone modifying licensed material must indicate that the original has been modified. This ensures that changes made to the original material–whether or not the licensor approves of them–are not attributed back to the licensor.

So there are two things here: 1) when you delete an account you basically waive your attribution requirement. This wouldn't require SE to remove your name, but it definitely **allows** them to do it according to the license. 2) there is a requirement for SE to remove the name if the owner of a CC-BY-SA-4.0 work requests removal. Note that this doesn't fully apply to content licensed to SE under an older CC license, but in those cases 1. still applies.

Also note that this means that if a user doesn't waive their rights, nor requests to be disassociated that SE can't remove the attribution without also removing their content (e.g. an underage user would have to be deleted with their content unless they waive their rights). Not sure how SE currently handles this.

Comment: Honestly, I'm not convinced that tying an account to attribution is valid. That sounds like coercion to try to force you to keep your account. While it might not be directly listed, I feel like the GDPR or something similar would require those 2 things to be separate. Deleting your account should not require you to give up your rights to attribution.

Comment: @samanthaj I would ask the inverse: What would the deletion of an account entail except the removal of attribution. Dissociation from the platform is the goal of requesting an account deletion. If they would keep the attribution they wouldn't have gotten rid of the most important aspect of your account.

Comment: Accounts are a way to keep your contact info and send you ads. S.O. maybe be better than most websites but it's not unreasonable to want to close an account and lording "if you do we'll remove all attribution" over you doesn't sound like typical S.O. The excuse to remove attribution seem really flimsy to me. If I quote someone else I'm required to put attribution. Why is S.O. suddenly off the hook? I didn't ask stop being attributed. I just asked to close my account.

Comment: Further, the most common way to attribute something found on S.O. off S.O is to [link to the question or answer on S.O](https://github.com/search?q=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F&type=code). So when S.O. removes attribution suddenly all those links are in violation of the license as they are not longer actually providing attribution. You can argue that's not S.O. problem but I hope it at least shows this issue isn't so black and white. Also don't get the push back. Why would it be hard for S.O. to keep attribution?

Comment: "Why would it be hard for S.O. to keep attribution?" One would need to ask the company for that. Only they know why they are doing things the way they are doing them. All we could do here is just guessing.